# Dynamical set a onclick event in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

In my program I am cloning a html element and setting properties of its child. 
I want to set a onclick event to one of the child.

```
function renderEmails() {
  for (var email of participants) {
      var $clone = $("#avator").clone();
      $clone.children(':nth-child(1)').text(email);
      $clone.children(':nth-child(2)').attr('onclick', deleteParticipants(email));
      $clone.css("display", "block");
      $clone.appendTo("#participantsDiv");
   }
}
function deleteParticipants(emailDel) {
    for (var email of participants) {
        if (email === emailDel) {
            participants.splice(email, 1);
            renderEmails();
         }
    }
}
```

There is no errors, but no output.

Comment: are you sure the script runs? try console logging some values here and there to see where the code is running and what is inside certain var's at times, like this: `console.log($clone);` right after `$clone` was created

Comment: @RamondeVries yes it working fine, unless the click event